# Error: error updating S3 bucket ACL (mybucket): MalformedACLError

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am currently trying to import an AWS S3 bucket into my terraform codebase/state.

In order to do that I have:

1. Added the following code to my terraform codebase

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "mybucket" {
  bucket = "mybucket"
}
```

2. Then executed:

- `terraform import aws_s3_bucket.mybucket mybucket` => success
- `terraform apply -target aws_s3_bucket.mybucket mybucket` => success

3. Added the following code to my terraform codebase

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "mybucket_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id
  access_control_policy {
    grant {
      grantee {
        type = "CanonicalUser"
      }
      permission = "FULL_CONTROL"
    }
    owner {
      id = "<id_number>"
    }
  }
}
```

Where <*id_number*> is the **Canonical user ID** value.

4. Then executed:

- `terraform import aws_s3_bucket_acl.mybucket_acl mybucket` => success
- `terraform apply -target aws_s3_bucket_acl.mybucket_acl mybucket` => failure (see error below)

```
╷
│ Error: error updating S3 bucket ACL (mybucket): MalformedACLError: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
│   status code: 400, request id: <request_id>, host id: <host_id>
│ 
│   with aws_s3_bucket_acl.mybucket_acl,
│   on s3.tf line 11, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "mybucket_acl":
│   11: resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "mybucket_acl" {
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong in my terraform code?

How do I correct this code to properly apply and maintain my bucket ACL in terraform?

Any help is welcomed, thanks.

PS: I am noticing the following bug being reported [#28230](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/28230)

Comment: Why do you need the apply step here?

Comment: To make sure my code matches what the state is reflecting from the AWS Console. If terraform has nothing to change then it should just reflect that state but it is not, it is failing and that shouldn't happen in any case.

Answer (score 2):

After playing around with this terraform code I have found that contrary to what the Terraform documentation mentions for [aws_s3_bucket_acl](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_acl) under *grantee* the **id** is required (and not optional) or else you get this error. When I added that as follows:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "mybucket_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id
  access_control_policy {
    grant {
      grantee {
        id = "<id_number>"
        type = "CanonicalUser"
      }
      permission = "FULL_CONTROL"
    }
    owner {
      id = "<id_number>"
    }
  }
}
```

Terraform no longer complained and completed successfully.